# Should acceptance of an answer carry an automatic upvote from the questioner?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer, upvotes

Essentially, I wonder at questions I've found with an accepted answer, but 0 votes.  Random example: [Extjs Form Panel Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834066/extjs-form-panel-structure/23839183#23839183)  Now, I know the answerer here, and he's told me that he's gotten 0 votes (up or down) on this answer, yet it's been accepted.

I understand that it's possible for the accepted answer to have a net vote value of 0, but I'm wondering why someone would accept an answer without deeming it worthy of an upvote?

Wouldn't it make sense that accepting an answer implies an upvote to the answer?

Comment: Up voting is a privilege. The asker may not have earned it, at that time. But yes it is customary to do so.

Comment: If that were true, then Stack Exchange wouldn't have decoupled them the way they did.

Comment: Is it more common to accept a good answer or an unacceptable answer? If the former, then I'd choose to couple them by default, and allow the person to un-vote in the (much) rarer case that the answer helped, but wasn't of acceptable quality.

Comment: As @mikez alludes to; you should think of the up-vote as something totally separate. Something everyone gets, independent of who asked the question. A person asking might only have so many votes left, and may want to give up-votes to the other answers, but then accept one (which gives 5 more points). Or... whatever...

Comment: @RobertHarvey So, Stack Exchange hasn't changed anything since it launched?  "Because they did it that way the first time" is hardly a reason it should stay that way forever.

Comment: I gotta say, I probably won't be asking/suggesting anything else on Stackexchange.  Merely posing a (non-repetitive) question in order to foster a discussion (which actually happened), garnered me 16 downvotes, rather than 16 responses, even if all were "No, that's wrong".

Comment: @BillJames A bit late to the party here, but that's the point of meta. Downvotes here don't mean "you're wrong", they mean "I disagree". Having 16 responses to say "I disagree" would be a ton of noise to wade through. Downvotes are much less personal here than on the main site.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Hmm, on other Stack's, someone would say WHY they disagreed, and others would concur with that by upvoting that response, not 16 separate responses.  I thought upvotes on questions were for whether it was a good question or not, though I guess questions here are "feature requests", not really calls for discussion?  I guess, since no "total score" for this site really results, it's not that important which way people say "no".

Comment: @BillJames For feature requests, the [meta help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) explicitly calls out upvotes/downvotes for being about agreement with the request. It's more vague about discussion questions, but from what I've seen people tend to act similarly unless the question is extremely neutral. That said, meta is filled with the same people from regular SO, and drive-by downvotes are a common occurrence there, so don't be surprised to see the same here.

Comment: Look at Commonsware user, he answers a ton of questions but almost never upvotes.  I too am curious why someone takes the time to answer a question but doesn't think its good enough to upvote.  Why would you answer it if you think its not good enough for an upvote?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196780/possible-solution-for-accidentally-not-upvoting-accepted-answer

Comment: Statistics on (accepted + not upvoted) answers would shed light on this topic.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting

Comment: Why does this question have so many downvotes? I think it's an interesting topic for discussion.

Comment: @MattK As discussed in the comments.  Rather than discuss, usually people just upvote if they agree and downvote if they disagree.  It makes for an atmosphere where people are afraid to ask questions they don't know will be popular, but that's the way it is.

Comment: @BillJames Hmmm... I agree about the atmosphere. Does seem a bit cold. Can we vote on what voting should mean in meta? :S

Answer (score 14):

> Wouldn't it make sense that accepting an answer implies an upvote to the answer?

Usually it makes sense but not always. Acceptance of an answer should **not** carry an automatic upvote.

---

**Upvote denotes** that the answer was **helpful and well-researched**.

**Accepting an answer means** that OP believed that this is the **best solution to the posted problem**.

OP should be encouraged to upvote an accepted answer but it should not be mandatory/automatic.

Think of it as a great answer (which may help future visitor too) versus a technically correct answer (which may possibly be a code-only post). It takes time and effort to write a great answer, whereas a code-only post may not deserve an upvote but can be accepted because it worked for the OP.

Useful to the community -> Upvote. Useful to the OP -> Accept.

**Some other reasons** why these two should not be coupled:

- There are badges like [Tenacious](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) which are based on zero-score accepted answers. Then you have [Populist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist) given to the highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer.
- New users don't have privileges to upvote, they can only accept an answer. Also, votes get locked but accepted answers can be changed anytime. If there was an automatic upvote then will the system *auto-unupvote* it even though vote is locked?
- OP can mark self-answered posts as accepted, these will have to be handled separately if there is an automatic upvote on answer acceptance.

Comment: Just to emphasize one important point from this answer: A lot of questions are from new users. Until they have 15 rep points, they cannot upvote answers.

Comment: @RetoKoradi That's why there are so many 0 vote accepted answers, most of the time those that could vote don't bother, regardless of whether it is a "good" answer or not.

Answer (score 8):

No it should not.

- Accepted - helped original poster.
- Upvoted - quality answer.

So it is perfectly possible to have just-ok answer that helped original poster.

Comment: The tooltip for upvoting states "This answer is useful". It is hard for me to imagine an answer that *helped the OP*, which was not *useful for the OP*. They are essentially synonyms. Most of the posters [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting) agree.

Answer (score 6):

I am essentially copying [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246324/232130) here, now that SO Meta and SE Meta are separated.

What I value most of SO and other SE sites is the **legacy** built by the community, which makes the system useful in the long term. An essential part of this is a rating system that reflects **usefulness**. I have benefited quite a lot from it.

I think that the focus on this usefulness for the SO community is often relegated, in favor of the reputation earned by users. Both go together, that is how SO works, but

> When a decision is to be made, **usefulness + legacy should prevail as a criterion**.

Following up with this rationale, if accepting goes naturally with upvoting in an (overwhelming?) majority of cases, something that proactively favors the upvoting in these cases would be most convenient.

Now, the due answer to the specific question: ***Wouldn't it make sense that accepting an answer implies an upvote to the answer?***, I would say **YES, with an option for explicitly not upvoting**. But any other action favoring this will also be interesting.

Comment: Statistics on (accepted + not upvoted) answers would shed light on this topic.

Answer (score -10):

Based on Alexei's logic, then I believe that accepted answers should receive 1 upvote. If it helps the original poster, then the answer itself was quality enough to work with. Again this is only if it is confirmed from the poster the answer helps.