# Are up-vote reps included in acceptance rep or are they separate?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, upvotes

Recently, I asked a question. I up-voted an answer before accepting it. I wondered afterwards whether these two actions of mine had given 25 rep (10 for up-voting and 15 for accepting ), or just 15, to the answerer.

I know that up-voting is a privilege and accepting an answer is a right, so my question is not about why the latter does not imply the former. That has been made clear here: [Should acceptance of an answer carry an automatic upvote from the questioner?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269928/should-acceptance-of-an-answer-carry-an-automatic-upvote-from-the-questioner).

What I want to know is how SO handles rep calculation in a situation like I illustrated above.

Comment: Both votes count, so the OP of that answer got 25 rep

Comment: _"I wondered afterwards"_ - so visit their profile and check the reputation tab.

Comment: @rene, you have answered my question. Thanks

Comment: @CodeCaster, Thanks for the smart suggest .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you up vote an answer you give the user who wrote the answer +10 rep unless it is a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) in which case no rep is awarded.  When you down vote an answer the user gets -2 rep and you will get -1.  This is different than questions as you do not lose any reputation when you down vote a question.  When you accept and answer you get 2 rep and the user who wrote the answer gets 15 rep.

All of these actions a separate and stack with each other.  If you up vote and accept and answer then the user who wrote the answer gets 25 rep.  If you down vote the answer and accept the user would get 13 rep(I don't know why you would but you can).  If you chose not to vote but you do accept the answer the the user who wrote the answer will get 15 rep.

Comment: +1. No answer could be clearer and more straightforward. Thanks.