# Why would someone want to accept an answer, but NOT upvote it?

Tags: discussion

I see this quite often: Users accept answers, but they don't upvote them. It made me wonder: Why are they separated?

Why would you want to *accept* an answer, but *not* upvote it?

The criteria for an upvote (as shown on the tooltip) is simply "This answer is useful" - which makes perfect sense. Votes are supposed to help separate the useful and not so useful.

How could someone accept an answer and not find it useful?

**Update:** [Click to see your accepted answers with 0 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me%20%09isaccepted:yes%20score:0%20%09wiki:no%20%09is:answer) - There doesn't seem to be logic to it that I can discern.

Comment: You need 15 rep to upvote, 1 to accept.

Comment: I guess this question only really applies to users with 15+ rep.

Comment: I've honestly pretty much only seen that behavior on <15

Comment: People vote, or don't, for whatever reason they choose.

Comment: Why? Because *"They can"*

Comment: I haven't personally done this, but if I did it'd be to an answer that answered my question, but was poorly written, explained, or formatted. For instance, a code-only answer that I had to sort through myself to figure out how it worked. Technically answers the question, but not in my mind worthy of the upvote at that point.

Comment: Besides, not upvoting doesn't mean the answer is not useful

Comment: It happens, some users appear to treat an answer as either helpful or an acceptable solution but not both.  Pretty hard to step into their skin, no idea where that kind of reasoning could come from.  Not a winning strategy btw, I've seen such users no longer getting help.  I suspect contributors keep a little black book.

Comment: I know that when I was a SO pup, I would only accept. I guess I didn't realize that the OP could/should upvote as well (doesn't make sense when I think about it now but that's the way it was). I later went back and upvoted answers I accepted. There are some that I still haven't upvoted that basically told me what I already knew and said "you can't do what you want to do". Without a good explanation of *why* I couldn't, those don't seem very upvote worthy to me. Right or wrong? I don't know

Comment: I'm sure there's been various FRs about this before - one I recall was along the lines of "If the OP accepts the answer there should be an automatic upvote regardless of their rep"

Comment: This question was asked on SE meta many moons ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting

Comment: *I guess I didn't realize that the OP could/should upvote* @codeMagic - I can see how that could happens since you start off only being able to up accept. (Not that I think that should change, I can just see someone getting the idea that you do one or the other.)

Comment: Another thing to note: If you ask a question anonymously, you can't do *anything* on your question once your cookie for that session disappears. That happened to me on a different SE site where I didn't want my username associated with the question. (It's a shame since I got an excellent answer.)

Comment: @Jon You're probably referring to this FR: [Should acceptance of an answer carry an automatic upvote from the questioner?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269928/1842065)

Comment: I had been asking myself this for years, w.r.t. new users. Were they just unaware, or just being rude? None of the answers posted under this question nor the duplicate question spell the answer out quite as well as [Patrice's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311596/why-would-someone-want-to-accept-an-answer-but-not-upvote-it#comment278871_311596): `You need 15 rep to upvote, 1 to accept.`  It is a shame that it can't be posted as a one line answer to make it obvious. Old users often forget (as I had) what it is like to be a totally new user with a rep of 1.

Answer (score 18):

Interpret accepting an answer as *"This answered my question."*

Interpret upvoting as *"This answer is useful to others,"* by whatever measure you care to apply... it has broad applicability, it is clearly-written and informative, etc.

Answers which nudge an asker in the right direction may help solve his problem, without necessarily be useful to others *except in that very specific case.*

Answer (score 14):

There are obviously limitations on voting that are part of the system that would not allow you to vote on an answer at the same time that you accept it:

- Not enough rep to upvote
- Out of votes for the day

Beyond that, there is only reason, albeit, a very general reason - the answer is terrible and does not deserve an upvote.  While I have not had any myself in the few questions I've asked, there are situations I can think of that might not merit an upvote, but do answer the question.

For example

> **Question:** I want to `Foo` the `Bar` with a `Bat`
>   **Answer:** No, you cannot do that

If "No" is the actual answer (and there are no other better answers), then it is worthy of being accepted since it does answer the question, but without much explanation or a possible suggestion or work-around, I would have a hard time upvoting that answer.